# Can using getTransactionCount() + 1 prevent waiting for pending transactions?

Tags: pending-transactions, nonce, confirmations

I tested sending multiple transactions with a low time gap, and I knew that they will wait for previous transactions to be confirmed. I did not use Nonce in the transaction code as it is optional. But I would like to know, is there any way to send transactions without waiting for confirmation of previous ones?
I thought about using `nonce = getTransactionCount() + 1`, although, I am not sure is it correct or not? and which condition I have to set in it amoung `latest`, `earliest` or `pending` for this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about using `nonce = getTransactionCount() + 1`

Web3.js does it for you if you do not specify `nonce` explicitly, so it won't make any difference.

> Is there any way to send transactions without waiting for confirmation of previous ones?

Yes, exactly as you described it (sending them without waiting for confirmation of previous ones).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean I should not do anything special to achieve my goal?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi: Yup, simply don't wait for confirmation. Just keep the transaction hash (which is returned to you pretty much instantly), and check it later. Alternatively you can just check the state variables that your transactions change (assuming that each transaction independently changes something in the state).

Comment: Your direct and clear answer help me a lot. Thank you

Comment: @MohammadSaberi: You're welcome. Note that in this scheme you WILL need to increment the nonce explicitly, but WITHOUT relying on `getTransactionCount` for that (i.e., use your own internal counter).

Comment: you said web3 do increment itself automatically. I did not understand whad do you mean in your last comment

Comment: @MohammadSaberi: Web3 does it automatically (setting `nonce` to the value returned by `getTransactionCount`). But the nonce of your account will not really increment until the transaction is added to the blockchain, and until that happens, `getTransactionCount` will return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment Nonce "manually", do an internal control. You can make an array of sendSignedTransactions and after solving with Promise.all, one of the alternatives. As far as I know the queue supports up to 64 transactions.

At least on the Rinkeby network, you only receive the receipt when the next block is mined, so you would have the bottleneck of 4 transactions per minute.

Sending multiple chain events will require complicated logic if an error occurs.